# Type Not Found issue in Openfl Haxe Project

Tags: haxe, openfl

I am having issues with my openfl/Haxe project. I tries to import

`import flash.accessibility.AccessibilityProperties;`

But I am getting the error like this :

```
Type not found : AccessibilityProperties
```

Haxe and lime versions are latest versions.  the whole code is like below :

```
package mx.core;


import flash.accessibility.AccessibilityProperties; 
import flash.display.DisplayObject; 
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.display.IBitmapDrawable;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.display.Stage; 
import flash.events.IEventDispatcher; 
import flash.geom.Point; 
import flash.geom.Rectangle; 
import flash.geom.Transform;

interface IFlexDisplayObject extends IBitmapDrawable extends IEventDispatcher
{





    var visible(get, set) : Bool;    



    var rotation(get, set) : Float;    



    var name(get, set) : String;    



    var width(get, set) : Float;

    var measuredHeight(get, never) : Float;    



    var blendMode(get, set) : String;    



    var scale9Grid(get, set) : Rectangle;    



    var scaleX(get, set) : Float;    



    var scaleY(get, set) : Float;    

    var measuredWidth(get, never) : Float;    



    var accessibilityProperties(get, set):AccessibilityProperties;    



    var scrollRect(get, set) : Rectangle;    



    var cacheAsBitmap(get, set) : Bool;    



    var height(get, set) : Float;    

    var parent(get, never) : DisplayObjectContainer;     



    var opaqueBackground(get, set) : Dynamic;    



    var alpha(get, set) : Float;    

    var mouseX(get, never) : Float;    

    var mouseY(get, never) : Float;    



    var mask(get, set) : DisplayObject;    



    var transform(get, set) : Transform;    

    var loaderInfo(get, never) : LoaderInfo;    

    var root(get, never) : DisplayObject;    



    var x(get, set) : Float;    



    var y(get, set) : Float;    



    var filters(get, set) : Array<Dynamic>;    

    var stage(get, never) : Stage;


    function localToGlobal(param1 : Point) : Point
    ;

    function globalToLocal(param1 : Point) : Point
    ;

    function getBounds(param1 : DisplayObject) : Rectangle
    ;

    function setActualSize(param1 : Float, param2 : Float) : Void
    ;

    function hitTestPoint(param1 : Float, param2 : Float, param3 : Bool = false) : Bool
    ;

    function getRect(param1 : DisplayObject) : Rectangle
    ;

    function move(param1 : Float, param2 : Float) : Void
    ;

    function hitTestObject(param1 : DisplayObject) : Bool
    ;
}
```

The issue is exactly like below:

```
src/mx/core/IFlexDisplayObject.hx:4: characters 7-50 : Type not found : flash.accessibility.AccessibilityProperties
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OpenFL does not implement AccessibilityProperties so you can only use that property [on Flash target](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/blob/5d5f34ae3df3acf23fb5a0dce418d23ca7be39b5/externs/flash/flash/display/DisplayObject.hx#L14-L16).

You could try removing that property from your interface and see if that breaks anything, or creating a dummy class that has the required fields but doesn't do anything (to be placed in `flash/accessibility/AccessibilityProperties` as you'd expect)

Comment: I put the folder named accessibility under flash directory to the openfl directory. and the problem is fixed. I dont know how this solves the problem.